# Select Option Lost on Back Button & Search Results Reverts to Default Option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, cookies

I have a search form on a website for a school, where school staff members can be searched by "First Name" and/or "Last Name". Search can be narrowed down by "Type of Staff"

The default search is "Teachers", as that is the most popular term and common search performed.

All other school staff listings are hidden, unless user selects them via the drop down menu ( select & option ).

The problem is that if the user is looking for a "Daycare Staff member", clicks on one of the "Daycare Staff" to view her profile, then click the "back button", the default "Teachers" option is selected again and the previous option "Daycare Staff" is lost.

My question is, if I have to use cookies, how do I use cookies to not reset to  the default search option.

Is there another way, besides using cookies?

Here is an example of what the code of search form looks like:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="#">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_search_first" placeholder="Search by First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_search_last" placeholder="Search by Last Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="group" class="form-control">
              <option value="">Groups</option>
              <option value="Principle">Principle</option>
              <option value="Vice Principle">Vice Principle</option>                                                              
              <option value="Teachers" selected="selected">Teachers</option>              
              <option value="Daycare Staff">Daycare Staff</option>
              <option value="Educational Assistants">Educational Assistants</option>                                                              
              <option value="Special Needs Assistant">Special Needs Assistant</option>                                                            
              <option value="Human Resources">Human Resources</option>
              <option value="Day Time Caretaker">Day Time Caretaker</option>
              <option value="Night Time Caretakers">Night Time Caretakers</option>  
              <option value="School Administration">School Administration Staff</option>                                                              
        </select>                                                                                                           
        <div class="default"><input type="text" style="" class="form-control ShowTeachers" id="schoolTeachers" value="Teachers"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a database or flat text file, but why not use cookies if I may ask?

Comment: I don't mind cookies, I just want to see if there is another way. Where can i find a good tutorial for that?

Answer (score 0):

try to keep the selected group value in $_SESSION and update the group value from session, then the selected value stays as it is,even when the user goes back.

Comment: I ended up using a combination of PHP Sessions and Javascript Cookies to   address this problem.